# Make [google-bard] a synonym of [google-gemini]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

According to [its website](https://gemini.google.com/app), "Bard is now Gemini". The main tag should be something like [google-gemini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-gemini) or just [gemini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemini) with [google-bard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-bard) added as a synonym since many people still know it by the old name. I could also see adding the URL as another synonym ([gemini.google.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemini.google.com)), but that's not as important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now complete.

New tag [gemini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemini) with synonyms [google-gemini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-gemini) and [google-bard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-bard).

Tag name chosen based on actual naming convention of the app: **Gemini** not **Google Gemini**. This is analogous to **Gmail** as opposed to **Google Gmail**, and contrasts with other apps like **Google Calendar**, **Google Contacts**, etc.